# Several users add SPListItem

Tags: splistitem, splist

Will there be any problems (e.g. save conflicts) if several users at the same time will try to programmatically add `SPListItem` to `SPList`?

```
public override void Add(Contract contract)
{
    var listItem = List.Items.Add();
    GetListItem(contract, listItem);
    listItem.SystemUpdate(false);
}

protected override void GetListItem(Contract contract, SPListItem listItem)
{   
    listItem[Fields.Title] = contract.Name;
    listItem[Fields.BeneficiaryBirthdate] = contract.BeneficiaryBirthdate;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**,

There will be no save conflict when multiple users will add new item to the SharePoint List.

Answer (score 0):

As it is new Item, it wont give any error! if its update then you will get error if same item is getting updated by different users at same time